# Test worker thread with mocks

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-sdk, worker-thread

My Node application uses AWS SDK, and in order to mock it locally I am using Jest's [manual mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks). Basically I am placing in `__mocks__` folder barebone mock of AWS SDK that simulates methods I use - and during Jest tests *this* "AWS-SDK" is being called by the main code.

This works fine for the regular code flow. But when I invoke a worker thread (I am using [sync-thread](https://github.com/lambci/sync-threads/) library but this is true for regular worker usage) - code inside of the worker tries to call real AWS-SDK when running Jest tests.

Is there a way to make it use mocked one as well? Also environmental variables set in the worker don't persist for the caller thread - is this by design or could they be set this way?